# Can we process a request based on time limit and if it exceeds time limit the process must stop?

Tags: java, web-services, timeoutexception

Scenario: My application has web services(SOAP) and TIBCO third party System. Both are deployed in different servers. Both server has 8 instances.

Condition: Tibco server can only wait for 5 min from java web service. After that time out appears.

WebServices Job: To provided all the student details in the school - 1 million records. Though to process 1 million it takes time we introduced pagination concept. In Request we added stating position of the record and end position of a record. So it takes from 1 - 100000 from db and process.

Issue : Some hit takes more than 5 min and some takes less than 2 due to process data. so time out issues still exists  after pagination.(even if pagination count is reduced)

Question: What will be the best solution to avoid this?

My idea is to implement a thread concept and if the process time from java exceeds 4 or 4.5 mins then stop the existing processing data and give the response, with start and end index given by java service to hit at the next time. How can we implement this?

If this isn't a good solution, could you provide a better alternative?

Comment: If your client does not care about the response time, you should use an asynch interface (e.g. over JMS)

Comment: Tibco server can only wait for 5 min from java web service. After that time out appears. Tibco does not wait for the response. It register as timeout exception in client server

Comment: What @kaykay meant is that you may redesign this process in order to not wait for an answer from the web service and make it an asynchronous call. If this isn't possible, then it will be better to process less data or use another alternatives to improve the data processing e.g. caching, multi tasking, etc.